# Hosting WCF service on IIS

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis-6

I am trying to host a WCF service using IIS, (works fine in Cassini).  However when I host it in IIS I get the following error:

"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)"

I thought this might be due to IIS and windows authentication, so I changed the connectionstring to directly login to the database with a uid and password, makes no difference. I don't think I am getting that far, as I would expect a sql security error if that were the case.

I have set up a brand new server (2008), and still I get the same issues...

What setting to I need to implement to get this going?

**Example WCF Code**

```
private GenericDataClassesDataContext _db = new GenericDataClassesDataContext();

 public ReferenceValue[] GetReferenceValues()
        {
            try
            {
                return _db.ReferenceValues.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new FaultException(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="TtasConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=stdev07;Initial Catalog=Ttas;;uid=srvTtas;pwd=pa$$w0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <add name="TTASConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=STDEV07;Initial Catalog=IRF;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>      
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>   
        <extensions>
   <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="silverlightFaults" type="Moe.Tactical.GenericData.Wcf.SilverlightFaultBehavior, Moe.Tactical.GenericData.Wcf, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
   </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>   
    <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="SilverlightFaultBehavior">
             <silverlightFaults />
          </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="Moe.Tactical.GenericData.Wcf.GenericDataServiceBehavior">
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
             <!--<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />-->
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="winAuthBasicHttpBinding">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Moe.Tactical.GenericData.Wcf.GenericDataServiceBehavior" name="Moe.Tactical.GenericData.Wcf.GenericDataService">
                <!--bindingConfiguration="winAuthBasicHttpBinding" [in gap]-->
                <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightFaultBehavior"
                  contract="Moe.Tactical.GenericData.Wcf.IGenericDataService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost:3637"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
            </service>
        </services>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The settings you need are "SHOW_FULL_EXCEPTION" and "POST_THE_CODE"

Comment: On a side note, I can't work out how to debug it (so I can't get the full exception, and the faultexception is not working...), as when I change VS to use IIS rather than cassini, then I get the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Comment: Here's a thought: stop eating exceptions. Get rid of that try/catch block entirely. That way, maybe it will be logged in the Windows event log. If not, turn on WCF tracing and try again. It _will_ be in the WCF log.

Comment: ahh, as soon as I turned on the tracing the error message changed to "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\GenericData'".
which is obviously not the user name! will look into that further

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is in the following line of web.config:

```
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

You should change it to

```
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
```